# How to change FileInputStream image to image from resources?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have this line:

```java
//Creating an image
Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\\images\\image.png"));
```

I would like to change to this line, I would like to get the image from resources in IntelliJ and not from my PC's C drive, for example, but it doesn't work:

```java
Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("file:src/main/resources/images/image.png"));
```

or

```
Image image  = new Image(getClass().getResource("file:src/main/resources/images/image.png").toExternalForm());
```

I have an exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

Comment: what is the full stack trace for the exception?  And why not just use `Image image  = new Image(getClass().getResource("image.png").toExternalForm());`  provided image.png is in the same package hierarchy in resources as the calling class
`

Comment: ie: the calling class is in `src/main/java/some/package` then image.png will be in `src/main/resources/some/package`

Comment: It doesn't work. I put image.png to the the same package what class file. I have tried put image.png to the resources but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Please show the relative path of the class calling for new image, the relative path of where you have image.png, and the full exception stacktrace

Comment: I posted everything in my post. What does it mean the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Try ```Image image  = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/image.png"));```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method` does not give enough information for anyone to help you..    The class calling for a new Image (I'm guessing Application.java) is the path `src/main/java/Application.java`? if it is, then to use my suggested code, image.png file must have the path `src/main/resources/image.png'.  You did not use my suggestion, but instead modified it, there is no reason to put `file:` and you didn't move the image.png to where it needs to be for the class loader to pick it up via the call to getResource

Comment: @codeflush.dev has the correct answer if you don't want to move the file

Comment: @codeflush.dev yes, it works

Answer (score 0):

You simply need do like this.

In project put your images:

```
ProjectName/image.png
```

[example of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Cul.png)

and then

```
   Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("image.png"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The path is determined from the classpath (= root) which is the case of `src/main/resources`.
Thus

```
Image image  = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.png"));
```

...should work.

You get get some more details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java).